# Python list comprehension when creating a list

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I'm trying to generate a list of random numbers. I thought this would be a good time to use list comprehension to shorten the code. The only problem is that now I have this unused "i" variable. Is there a way to write it without needing that variable, or should I not worry about it too much?

```
int_list = [random.randrange(0, 50) for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: Your question is not about a list comprehension. Please [edit] your title so that it reflects your actual question, which seems to be about an unused variable. See [ask]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `_` instead which acts like a placeholder for variables you don't need either in loops

```py
int_list = [random.randrange(0, 50) for _ in range(10)]
```

```py
def print_hello():
   print("Hello")

for _ in range(10): # we don't need the value of "range(10)" in 
      print_hello   # each iteration.
```

or to ignore outputs from a function

```py
def func(a,b):
    c = a+b
    return a,b,c

a,_,c = func(2,3) # we don't need store the output "b" here, 
                  # thus we "ignore" it using the "_"
print(a) # 2
print(c) # 5
```

With all that said, you could aswell just use the `i` instead - it is just a convention using `_`

Answer (score 0):

Summary: it's not something to worry about.

A list comprehension creates a function namespace for its execution, including slots for local variables. When you write:

```
[random.randrange(0, 50) for i in range(10)]
```

`i` is a local variable that is deleted when the comprehension completes. It won't overwrite an `i` defined in the enclosing namespace and won't take any space after the operation is done.

It's common to use `_` for variables that aren't used elsewhere. That is just a convention that makes it a little easier for people reading your code.